# Typescript conditioned dynamic model type declaration

Tags: typescript

Does typescript have something like dynamic type declaration, where based on the value variable type it will assign proper custom model?

```
export type ModelDeclaration = {
 [T: string]: typeof ModelDeclaration[T] === 'string' ? ModelStringInput : ModelIntInput;
}

export type ModelIntInput = {
    between?: Array<number | null> | null;
    attributeExists?: boolean | null;
    attributeType?: ModelAttributeTypes | null;
};

export type ModelStringInput = {
    attributeType?: ModelAttributeTypes | null;
    size?: ModelSizeInput | null;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is using a variable to discriminate between two options:

```
export type ModelDeclaration = 
{
 value: string
 type: 'string'
 model: ModelStringInput
} |
{
 value: number
 type: 'int'
 model: ModelIntInput
}

export type ModelIntInput = {
    between?: Array<number | null> | null;
    attributeExists?: boolean | null;
    attributeType?: ModelAttributeTypes | null;
};

export type ModelStringInput = {
    attributeType?: ModelAttributeTypes | null;
    size?: ModelSizeInput | null;
};


const parseModel = (model: ModelDeclaration) => {
  if (model.type === 'string') {
     // Here typescript knows that model.model is ModelStringInput and model.value is string
  }

  if (model.type === 'int') {
     // Here typescript knows that model.model is ModelIntInput and model.value is number
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these exist! However they are kinda limited in some aspects, in my opinion the handbook explains it pretty well: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

However your example looks a bit like you could just write a function where you wrap it into